# Conditionally replacing column values with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(col1 = rep("a",6), col2 = c(1,1,1,2,3,1))
```

Now I want to replace all the 1 in col2 with value "bigDog". I can do it using the data.frame spirit:

```
dt$col2[dt$col2==1,] <- "bigDog"
```

But I wonder if there is a different way, more *"data.table oriented"*?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Had you not wanted to change the type of the column, you'd do:

```
dt[col2 == 1, col2 := 123]
```

With the type change, you can do:

```
dt[, col2 := as.character(col2)][col2 == "1", col2 := "bigDog"]
```

If you don't change the type first, "bigDog" will get coerced to integer, i.e. `NA`. You'll also get a bunch of warnings about that of course.

Note that besides less cumbersome syntax, using `:=` has the advantage of not making extra copies of data (as `<-` will) and instead modifies in place.

Comment: Assuming I don't want to change the column type, how can I apply the first usage to multiple (named) columns?

Comment: @rimorob sure - `dt[condition,\`:=\`(col2 = 123, col3 = 234, ...)]`

Comment: How about doing multiple conditions at once on the same column? E.g. changing 1 to "bigDog" and 2 to "smallDog"?

Answer (score 1):

Aditionally you could use the library plyr

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
dt <- data.table(col1 = rep("a",6), col2 = c(1,1,1,2,3,1))
dt <- mapvalues(dt[,col2], c(1), c("BigDog"))
```