# How to use the apply family of functions to adjust values of a list by grouped index

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, apply, distribution

Ok so I have an excel sheet with a variety of scenarios and values, and what I'd like to do is transform some of those values by using a random distribution. I'm able to do that one scenario at at time, but I'd like to be able to do it in a more compact way, possibly with the apply function family. Here is a small version of my matrix which I use as a data.table with setDT:

```
matrixfromexcel = 

Scenario char num1 num2 num3 val1 val2 val3

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

1        1    0    4    8    1.22 2.31 7.33

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542 

2        5    2    0    1    4.2  5.011 12.542

...

1200    66    8    1    0    555  120 1700
```

So as you can see, the scenario number separates the values into groups, and there is a large number of scenarios, up to 1000's+. Here is what I've used in order to add random numbers from a normally distributed function to the values of one column of one scenario:

```
matrixfromexcel[Scenario == 1, val1 := val1+rnorm(8, 1.22, 1)]
```

Where 8 is the number of different random numbers, 1.22 is the value I want the mean centered at, and 1 is the # of standard deviations I want in the random numbers.

So if I wanted to loop around from Scenario 1 to 1000, should I try an apply function or just try to use a loop? If apply function, could you show me your suggestion? Thank you

Comment: fyi -- in `rnorm(8, 1.22, 1)` 1 is the _value_ of one standard deviation, rather than the number of standard deviations. `sd(rnorm(x,y,z))` will by definition have a value close to `z`

Comment: @arvi1000 yes, the # of rows of each scenario will be fixed

Comment: I don't understand the intention. If you're just adding a random value to each, why not do it all at once i.e. `matrixfromexcel[Scenario %in% 1:1000, val1 := val1 + rnorm(length(val1), 1.22, 1)]`? What are you hoping to achieve by adding a random value for each `Scenario` through a series of separate steps?

Comment: Hello @IceCreamToucan (love the name), because I'm not sure if I will have the same parameters for each number. The SD or # of values for the random numbers generated may change for each scenario, and so I want to have the granularity to change that if needed. Feel free to suggest a solution without it too, for reference if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `by` argument in `data.table` and the special operator `.N` which refers to the # of rows within each group. Here's something to get you started:

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.4.4
dt <- data.table(Scenario = rep(c(1,2,3), times = c(8,5,3)), val1 = rep(c(1.22, 4.2, 6), times = c(8,5,3)))
dt[, new_val := val1 + rnorm(.N, val1, 1), keyby = Scenario]
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

For transparency, I created `new_val` versus overwriting `val1` but you can modify that as you see fit. Also note, you currently passed in 1 to the `sd` parameter for `rnorm()`. If that's what you intended, great. If not, modify accordingly.

Comment: Ok great @Chase, thank you! If I wanted to specify Scenario with a start and end value, then could I do something like 1:1:1200?

Comment: and if someone wants to use a character value instead of numeric please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536771/conditionally-replacing-column-values-with-data-table