# How to keep date format in data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table

This is the sample of my dataset:

```
> sample
        ORDER_DATE   SHIPMENT_DATE
 1:     2021-08-01    2022-12-31
 2:     2021-08-01    2024-06-30
 3:     2021-08-01    2022-12-31
 4:     2021-08-01    2022-12-31
 5:     2021-08-01    2021-08-31
 6:     2021-08-01    2024-06-30
 7:     2021-08-01    2021-08-31
 8:     2021-08-01    2021-08-31
 9:     2021-08-01    2021-08-31
10:     2021-08-01    2021-08-31
```

My goal is to subtract one day from `SHIPMENT_DATE` when it is the same as `ORDER_DATE` using `data.table` package. The problem is that whatever I try, the format of `ORDER_DATE` changes to `numeric`.

For example

```
>   sample[, SHIPMENT_DATE := ifelse(SHIPMENT_DATE==ORDER_DATE, SHIPMENT_DATE-1, SHIPMENT_DATE)]
> head(sample$SHIPMENT_DATE)
[1] 19357 19904 19357 19357 18870 19904
```

Then, when I try to convert it back to date, the values in `SHIPMENT_DATE`column, which should have been changed to `2021-07-31` are `2021-08-31`.

This problem also arose when I tried to create a reproductible example:

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(ORDER_DATE = structure(c(18840, 18840, 18840, 
18840, 18840, 18840, 18840, 18840, 18840, 18840), class = "Date"), 
    SHIPMENT_DATE = structure(c(19357, 19904, 19357, 19357, 18870, 
    19904, 18870, 18870, 18870, 18870), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x37dead8>, .Names = c("ORDER_DATE", 
"SHIPMENT_DATE"))
```

Comment: I think the issue is the `ifelse` - not data.table as such. I think you can avoid it like: `dt[SHIPMENT_DATE == ORDER_DATE, SHIPMENT_DATE := SHIPMENT_DATE - 1]` - also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects

Comment: try using as.Date while subtracting e.g. `as.Date(SHIPMENT_DATE -1)`

Comment: Also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536771/conditionally-replacing-column-values-with-data-table

Comment: Since you are using `data.table` use `fifelse` instead of `ifelse`.